# exploding string to remove path

Tags: php, explode

My script is returning the following path.

`/home/vol14_2/project.com/b22_16126933/test.project.com/htdocs/php/api.php`

I want to remove the rest and end up with the file name.

I know I have to explode the string, I just don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: **"I know I have to explode the string"** actually you don't need `explode` here.

Comment: My mistake. I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename("/home/vol14_2/project.com/b22_16126933/test.project.com/htdocs/php/api.php");
//api.php
```

OR [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/home/vol14_2/project.com/b22_16126933/test.project.com/htdocs/php/api.php');
echo $path_parts['basename']; // since PHP 5.2.0
//api.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$path = "/home/vol14_2/project.com/b22_16126933/test.project.com/htdocs/php/api.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "api.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "api"
?>
```